# C++ remove value from end of char

Tags: c++, char, delimiter

This simply gets each delims values from an array of words called `inputArray` and goes to the next word after every loop of the while.

each word is called `sub`.

The problem is once a word with an 's' is found at the end, I want to remove the 's' and make `sub` = the new word.

My current method turns sub back into a string called `stringTemp` and then removes the 's' and turns it back into a the char `sub`.

```
char inputDelim[] = " ";
char* sub = strtok(InputArray, inputDelim);
while(sub) 
{
    //This sets up the ability to find if 's' is at the end of the word 
    int n = strlen(sub);
    int v = n;
    char *vw = &sub[0u];
    v--;

    /////////////////////
    //The problem is here
    /////////////////////
    if(vw[v] == 's')
    {
        string stringTemp = string(sub);
        stringTemp.erase(stringTemp.end() - 1);
        sub = str.c_str();//This does not work. Can not convert const char* into char*
        s = 1;
        r = 1;
    }
    ...lots more code...
    sub = strtok(NULL, inputDelim);
}
```

sub is used further in the code for different means.

Can anyone assist with making this method work, OR show me another another way I could remove the 's' at the end of the `sub` char?

I shouldn't be struggling with this, but sadly I am.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? You aren't doing anything with the value of `sub`.

Comment: You immediately overwrite `sub` anyway , with `sub = strtok(NULL, inputDelim);` so it is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Your question title makes absolutely no sense! There's nothing like an _end of char_. `char` values are indivisable entities. (stay away from `strtok()` BTW).

Comment: Thats why I'm asking for a way to do it. I gave my current method that doesn't work while asking for any other possible ways to go about it. And I made some changes to the explanation. There are a couple hundred more lines of code after this block. This is just new material I'm adding.

Comment: Change that block to `if(vw[v] == 's') vw[v] = 0;`

Comment: This will be much simpler if you use (GASP!) C++. Create a `std::istringstream`, initializing it with the contents of `InputArray`. Write a loop that extracts words from that stream (`std::string word; str >> word;`). If the word ends with `s`, remove the `s`. Done.

Comment: Use `std::string`, `std::string.length() - 1`.  Don't use character arrays.

Comment: @Hennry *OR show me another another way* -- [Another way](https://ideone.com/smDoZw).  I didn't post this as an answer, since I'm tired of being burned by "I can't use that because my book/teacher/whatever has not explained it".

Comment: @user0042 I think he meant "Remove char from end of string" and he's a non-English speaker.

Comment: You have a perfectly good string to work with in `stringTemp`, why not work with that?

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem exactly where you pointed out:

```
//...
int v = n;
char *vw = &sub[0u];
v--;

/////////////////////
//The problem is here
/////////////////////
if(vw[v] == 's') // v points the the NULL char at the end of vw.

// should read:
if(vw[v - 1] == 's') // v points the the last char of string vw
```

The main issue is that once you've started using strtok on your InputArray, you should not mess with it. strtok pretty much owns your string's contents, and even modifies it.  Your trying to write into `sub` (which points inside `InputArray`) effectively breaks `strtok`'s internal logic.

You could have saved yourself the irritant bug by working with std::string from the get to. strtok() is far from being perfect...

This code is for C++03. C++11 introduced std::find_if_not, and deprecated std::not1.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool is_space(char c)
{
    return isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) != 0;
}

int main()
{
    string no_s;
    //...
    string phrase = "hello world and its riches";
    string::iterator p1;
    string::iterator p2 = phrase.begin();
    while ((p1 = find_if(p2, phrase.end(), not1(ptr_fun(is_space)))) != phrase.end())
    {
        p2 = find_if(p1 + 1, phrase.end(), is_space);

        string sub(p1, p2);
        if (*sub.rbegin() == 's')
            sub.resize(sub.length() - 1);

        no_s += sub + " ";
    }

    if (no_s.length())
        no_s.resize(no_s.length() - 1);

    cout << no_s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vw[v]` is the last character of the string, `vw[v+1]` (i.e. `vw[strlen(vw)]`) is the null terminator

Comment: Oh..I've missed the v--.  Too many variables meaning the same thing in that code...